# What is this "swscan.apple.com"?

Tags: macos, monterey

[image]

Is there an option to remove it, or resume to whatever the *default* was?

Answer (score 5):

I just went and manually checked for software updates, since I hadn't seen any updates in a while. I'm currently running macOS Monterey (was on 12.1). It told me my Mac was up to date after doing the check for updates.

It was then that I noticed this message about "swscan.apple.com".  I clicked the "Details" link and it popped up a dialog asking if I'd like to reset the update setting to the default. So I selected the option to reset to the defaults.

After resetting it to the default, I closed the system settings window. Then it immediately showed the red notitifcation icon atop the system settings icon in the dock. So I opened it and -- lo and behold -- software update said there was an update for my Mac: macOS Monterey 12.2.

So it *seems* that I wasn't getting any updates until I clicked that "Details" link and selected to reset to the default update settings.

The whole thing is a bit odd as I've never changed update settings and never run any beta versions of macOS or anything like that.

Answer (score 4):

`swscan.apple.com` *is* the default -- it's Apple's site that serves catalogs and metadata about available software updates (the updates themselves are served from `swcdn.apple.com`). I'm not sure why it's shown explicitly there; maybe it's being set by a profile, or something like that. But if it's being set by something explicitly, it's just being set to what it would be by default anyway.

P.s. According to the page for [Reposado](https://github.com/wdas/reposado) (a tool for running your own update server),

> In macOS Big Sur, Apple has removed the ability for `softwareupdate`
> to be pointed to a non-Apple sucatalog. This means you cannot use a
> Reposado server to serve Apple software updates to Big Sur (and
> presumably later versions of macOS) clients.

But if you're seeing that in Monterey... maybe Apple brought the option back?

Comment: In my experience, this often appears after using the beta version of MacOS and then updating to the stable version. I think the beta version leaves some sort of debris behind. This is one of the most common "errors" (Well, it's not much of an error, but still.)

Comment: So that's the site that serves data about updates, but why are we getting a message that it is managing our computers?  That's a really creepy message for someone who owns their own computer and is not having it managed by a company. If you know the answer, can you answer here → https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/439294/3553 ?