# Manually manage the download of OS updates?

Tags: macos, software-update

I'm on Big Sur 11.6.5. The system tried to upgrade to 12.1 four times. Each time it spent 1 hour downloading, then restarted and I'm still on 11.6.5 (no error).

Someone said that I need to first upgrade to 11.6.7. I've tried that 3 times now. Each time it does a very slow download, hangs a while as the progress bar is hitting completion, then says the download failed.

I'm sick of re-downloading the same updates. Can I manually download the update(s) and somehow kickoff the upgrade using the already-downloaded file(s)?

[image: download failed]

Comment: "Updates for this mac are managed by swscan.apple.com" Click the Details… button & reset defaults. Try again. That's a bug or a beta version [google isn't sure which]

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/439294/85275 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/432585/85275 don't really come to any satisfactory conclusion either.

Comment: @Tetsujin Interesting callout. I don't see a *Details...* link for that pop-up though.

Comment: It's not in the popup, it's in the main control panel behind it. BTW, it shouldn't even be thinking about 12.1 any more. 12.4 is current.

Comment: Try downloading the full installer for macOS Big Sur 11.6.7 using this link: https://apps.apple.com/app/macos-big-sur/id1526878132 and use it to upgrade your computer to the latest release.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Good answer

Comment: Try to run `softwareupdate -i -a`.

Answer (score 1):

You can address this downloading the full installer of the current latest version of macOS Big Sur (11.6.7 as of this writing) by using the following link:

- https://apps.apple.com/app/macos-big-sur/id1526878132

Run this installer to upgrade your system to macOS Big Sur 11.6.7 and then upgrade to macOS 12.4.

It would be a good idea to have a working backup of your system/data before you attempt the upgrade(s).

Answer (score 1):

The download error is mostly related to the network issue from Apple server. It works sometimes by restarting the router or switch to another network provider such as mobile hotspot if possible.

If this does not, there is a open source app called MIST that can download macOS firmware manually.

https://github.com/ninxsoft/Mist

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

On the commandline you can use something like `softwareupdate -l`: https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/update-macos-terminal-command/

Comment: Answers should be more than just link. Please include the relevant parts directly in your answer so people don't need to hunt for it offsite. This will also ensure the answer stays relevant even if the link breaks.